# Force owner of all files in the folder "/var/www" are user www-data

Tags: php, apache, debian, sftp, chmod

I have a dedicated server, installed with Debian, Apache and PHP installed using "sudo apt-get install php5 php5-curl" command.

You can force all created files in folder and sub​​-directories are always user www-data?

If I log into sftp and I send it to a file on FTP, it is always as root, because I'm logged in as root, it is also possible to change, for example, I want to send the file to the server logged in as root but it is his owner www-data?

Comment: you have to be user www-data to create as user www-data but after the fact you can issue a command such as `chown -R www-data:www-data /files/xx/yy/`

Comment: Thanks :) This command I have used here, it works, changes in all files recursively from www folder, but it is only at the time of command, what I want is something definitive, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Having all files under `www-data` being owned by the web server - assuming write permissions by default - is dangerous, as a bug in a script or the web server itself could lead to source code injection.

The files under `/var/www` shouldn't be owned by the web server unless a certain web application really needs write access to a folder.

Even then and especially in a shared hosting environment there are better solutions than making the web server owner of such directories because this would allow every other PHP script - started by the web server - to write into that directory.

Comment: "The files under /var/www shouldn't be owned by the web server unless a certain web application really needs write access to a folder."

The files in /var/www then who should be? I always knew you were www-data

Comment: If it is a single application server the files may be owned by `root`.. Or something like `website_owner` (better)